# How to resize a VirtualBox vmdk file

Tags: virtualbox

I've run out of space on a virtual machine disk which is a vmdk and need to resize the virtual image. Resizing with the command

```
vboxmanage modifyhd Machine-disk1.vmdk --resize 30720
```

gives the error

```
Progress state: VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED
VBoxManage: error: Resize hard disk operation for this format is not implemented yet!
```

How can I resize a vmdk image?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

I was able to resize the vmdk by cloning it and then modifying and resizing.

```
vboxmanage clonehd "virtualdisk.vmdk" "new-virtualdisk.vdi" --format vdi
vboxmanage modifyhd "new-virtualdisk.vdi" --resize 30720
```

Comment: Thanks for this. For anyone who gets the error: `VBoxManage.exe: error: Code CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE (0x80080005)` while trying to run this command on windows, Run the Command Prompt as a non-administrator.

Comment: @BradFJacobs, but of course. That's the logical thing, after all. :P

Comment: This leaves the file in VDI format, which doesn't answer [Brian's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/390708) question of "How can I resize a vmdk image?"

Comment: Note, after resizing your vmdk file, you have to expand your partition in the VM by booting your with eg. gparted-live

Comment: For info: In linux (mint) it worked only without using double quotes for `virtualdisk.vmdk` like this : `vboxmanage clonehd virtualdisk.vmdk "new-virtualdisk.vdi" --format vdi
vboxmanage modifyhd "new-virtualdisk.vdi" --resize 30720`

Comment: @a1an the VM doesn't show snapshots with te new HD, since they are per VHD.

Comment: Ok... so now I have the .vdi file, but what do I do with it?

Comment: I got it
`VBoxManage: error: Failed to resize medium
VBoxManage: error: Resizing to new size 32212254720 is not yet supported for medium 'new-virtualdisk.vdi'
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED (0x80bb0009), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleModifyMedium(HandlerArg *)" at line 768 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp`

Comment: Hmm, can you just run clonehd again to get it back into vmdk format again? :)

Answer (score 832):

If you want to end having back a vmdk hard disk (maybe you are interested in using the disk in vwmare too), the complete steps are:

```
VBoxManage clonemedium "source.vmdk" "cloned.vdi" --format vdi
VBoxManage modifymedium "cloned.vdi" --resize 51200
VBoxManage clonemedium "cloned.vdi" "resized.vmdk" --format vmdk
```

The above will resize the hard disk up to 50GB (50 * 1024MB).


**To complete things** you need to resize the drive too! To achieve this, you might want to download [**gparted**](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) iso and boot from that iso to resize your drive (select the iso from within the virtualbox settings).

P.S. If your new size is too small, you'll get the same error even with your new vdi file.

Comment: This works! I want to add that you can also skip the third step and keep the disk in the VDI format.

I just did this with an Oracle 12c image and it works fine without the third step.

Just swap out the old "hard drive" for the cloned VDI one in the settings.

Also- don't forget to resize with Gparted, and you're good to go!

Comment: I did this too, but when I started VM I obtained error - when using VMDK from third step. With original VDI from second step it works.

Comment: For Windows users who haven't added VirtualBox to your PATH variable remember to change into the Virtual Box directory to use the VBoxManage program e.g. "cd C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox"

Comment: I have symlinked the vm file from my ssd to a big ssd. I had to specify the symlink path `VBoxManage clonehd "~/path/to/symlink/packer-centos-6.5-x86_64-disk1.vmdk" "/media/k0pernikus/thatFatSlowDisk/cloned_packer-centos-6.5-x86_64-disk1.vdi"` If you specfiy the real path, the command will crash due to `VBoxManage: error: Cannot register the hard disk`, as VBox thinks it's already defined somewhere else.

Comment: i believe, based on my own VM, that you want to use 5120000 as the resize value, not 51200, to achieve a 50GB new size. The value you use will be scaled up by one-thousand, not one-million. Also, you can use Windows built-in diskmgmt.msc-- no gparted needed.

Comment: Apparently, gparted got updated recently.  I downloaded that ISO and tried to boot it in VirtualBox, which it did to grub and it went through several menus, but it just locked up after that.  I downloaded an older version (2007) and it worked, however I had my main disk that I wanted to expand, but the guy who made set up the partition put the linux swap right after it, so I tried to move the swap over to the right and then expand the drive from 8GB to 48GB, but I couldn't figure out how.  I then tried to remove the swap and expand, but it failed.  Not sure what to do.

Comment: @Brandon: Try most recent gparted.iso after (temporarily) enabling EFI in VirtualBox for your VM.

Comment: if you have a windows you can then extend drive space in Manage/DiskManagement/Extend

Comment: Wow. I wasted hours trying and researching why the `clonehed` keeps creating volumes that are not supported by the `--resize`. Turns out that appending `--format vdi` to the `clonehd` is crucial!

Comment: The UUIDs mismatch after doing this (and replacing the original drive). VirtualBox 5.1.12 won't update the UUID automatically. I had to remove the hard drive from the list of known hard drives (File -> Virtual Media Manager) and then re-add it to the instance.

Comment: FYI: The size of the file "resized.vmdk" after resizing will STILL appear as the original size in Windows (in my case 10 GB, even after ``--resize 51200``. But when you load the file in VirtualBox, it will show the actual resized size (50 GB).

Comment: The last step (disk size extension) can be performed with  Disk Utility where you can select your disk and extend it to claim the extra available space

Comment: This works also in case of FreeBSD. The only thing I additionally had to do is execute `gpart recover ada0` because the free space was shown as "corrupted" and could not be used at the beginning.

Comment: For some reason, command #1 kept returning error `Cannot register the hard disk 'Windows Server 2019.vmdk.old' {ef4bc2d9-26dc-4758-82e6-a5c3c31339d1} because a hard disk 'Windows Server 2019.vmdk' with UUID {ef4bc2d9-26dc-4758-82e6-a5c3c31339d1} already exists` even though I'd removed it from the list of known media. To fix this, I had to first use command `.\VBoxManage internalcommands sethduuid "Windows Server 2019.vmdk.old"`.

Comment: This works for me , i just perform above 2 steps , then mounted the new image , login to the system , install the  gparted  in the VM https://gparted.sourceforge.io/download.php,  launch the gparted in the VM  , resize the disk size.   https://askubuntu.com/questions/409205/how-to-extend-partition-with-free-space-that-is-before-it-using-gparted

Answer (score 48):

I have a Windows 7 client on a Mac host and this post was VERY helpful. Thanks.

I would add that I didn't use gparted. I did this:

1. Launch new enlarged vmdk image.
2. Go to Start and right click Computer and select Manage.
3. Click Disk Management
4. You should see some grayed space on your (in my case) C drive
5. Right click the C drive and select Extend Volume.
6. Choose size and go

Sweet! I preferred that to using a 3rd party tool with warnings about data loss.

Cheers!

Answer (score 35):

**vmdk's** :

- *Rather fixed size allocation (step 1,2).*
- *Even after expansion, not readily available inside the vmdk's OS (step 3,4,5)*

**STEPS:**

**1)** convert to ".vdi" first - `VBoxManage clonehd v1.vmdk v1.vdi --format vdi`

**2)** expand the size using command-line (Ref: [tvial's blog](http://tvi.al/resize-sda1-disk-of-your-vagrant-virtualbox-vm/) for step by step info)

OR

expand from the [Virtual Media Manager](https://www.howtogeek.com/124622/how-to-enlarge-a-virtual-machines-disk-in-virtualbox-or-vmware/) in VirtualBox.

[ NOW - INSIDE VM ]

**3)** Expand the size of drive, with new allocation (e.g. for Ubuntu running on virtual-machine : use [GParted](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dmoving-space-between-partitions))
[image]
[image]

**4)** Extend the [filesystem](https://www.linuxtechi.com/extend-lvm-partitions/) - `lvextend -L +50G <file-system-identifier>`

ILLUSTRATION:

```
$ lsblk
NAME                       MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
...
sda                          8:0    0   200G  0 disk 
└─sda1                       8:1    0   200G  0 part 
  ├─myfs-vg-cloud          253:0    0    99G  0 lvm  /
  └─myfs-vg-swap-1         253:1    0   980M  0 lvm  [SWAP]


$ lvextend -L +100G /dev/mapper/myfs-vg-cloud

$ lsblk
NAME                       MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
...
sda                          8:0    0   200G  0 disk 
└─sda1                       8:1    0   200G  0 part 
  ├─myfs-vg-cloud          253:0    0   199G  0 lvm  /
  └─myfs-vg-swap-1         253:1    0   980M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

**5)** Extend the ["/home"](https://www.linuxtechi.com/extend-lvm-partitions/) - `resize2fs <file-system-identifier>`

ILLUSTRATION:

```
$ df -h /home/
Filesystem                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/myfs-vg-cloud         97G   87G  6.0G  94%   /

$ resize2fs /dev/mapper/myfs-vg-cloud

$ df -h /home/
Filesystem                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/myfs-vg-cloud         196G   87G  101G  47%  /
```

Your system must now be ready to use, with extended allocations !!

Comment: VBoxManage clearly does not to the trick, I think you've confused VDI and VMDK file formats

Comment: No confusion, just have a look to the link. VMDK has to be converted to VDI be processed.

Comment: @tvial - unfortunately, AFAICS, the process of converting VMDK to VDI will lose any snapshots you have, which is unacceptable for many people.  Therefore just stating it "does the trick" is a bit of an exaggeration..

Comment: @Jules, my answer is related to the question. Brian was trying to use VBoxManage and I'm not only stating that it does. I spent hours writing a stem by step blog post with screenshot. There are probably missing information regarding snapshots, you're right.

Comment: Well, sure, but it's just not the best solution.  The answers that provide recommendations for software that will resize a VMDK without converting to VDI (e.g. the answers provided by @micwallace and @davidehrman) are clearly better solutions for many people (and it's not clear whether the original asker is one of them or not).

Answer (score 31):

Actually, Only this these commands are needed:

```
VBoxManage clonehd "source.vmdk" "cloned.vdi" --format vdi
VBoxManage modifyhd "cloned.vdi" --resize 51200
```

Then, you can select cloned.dvi in Virtualbox GUI storage.

After that, start the virtual windows and expand your C disk as the methods of Code Chops.

It is not necessary to convert the *.vdi file to *.vmdk file back.

Answer (score 23):

Since this is a vmdk file, you could use VMWare's `vdiskmanager`, if it's available for your platform. VMWare has x86 Linux, Windows, and OS X versions [here](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1023856) (see "Attachments" on the right rail).

And then you just do:

```
1023856-vdiskmanager-windows-7.0.1.exe -x 30720M Machine-disk1.vmdk
```

It avoids having to clone, then expand the disk. Now, the downside is you need the extra tool, and vmdk is VMWare's disk format, and you're still using Virtualbox, so there could be incompatibilities.

`qemu-img` might also work, but I'm not sure if it supports resizing vmdk files. It would look something like:

```
qemu-img resize Machine-disk1.vmdk +8G
```

And just a reminder, with both, you still have to grow the partition after resizing the underlying disk. All these tools are essentially `dd if=/dev/old_disk of=/dev/new_disk bs=16M`.

Comment: The link to download vdiskmanager didn't work for me. I download the VMWare fusion trial from https://download3.vmware.com/software/fusion/file/VMware-Fusion-11.5.1-15018442.dmg, then mounted the .dmg file. vdiskmanager tool is then available at /Volumes/VMware\ Fusion/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmware-vdiskmanager.

Answer (score 18):

Tried all the solutions here, but nothing seemed to work. After hours of digging I found this [blog](http://learningdocker.com/resizing-boot2docker-disk-volumes/) post and like magic everything works. I had to make little adjustments so here is the modified version. Tested with Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87.

Once developers really start containerising their applications, they often generate a large number of images and quickly fill up the 20GB hard drive space allocated to the Docker virtual machine by default. To make sure the Docker virtual machine has plenty of disk space, we should resize /dev/sda1 to a number that is more reasonable.

1. Download [GParted Live CD/USB/HD/PXE Bootable Image](https://gparted.sourceforge.io/download.php/download.php).
2. Stop the Docker virtual machine `docker-machine stop default`.
3. Boot2Docker package installer ships with a VMDK volume, which VirtualBox’s native tools cannot resize. In order to resize the Docker disk volume, first clone the VDI volume from the default VMDK volume `vboxmanage clonehd /full/path/to/disk.vmdk /full/path/to/disk_resized.vdi --format VDI --variant Standard`.
4. Resize the newly cloned VDI volume to the desired capacity. We recommend at least 64GB `vboxmanage modifyhd /full/path/to/disk_resized.vdi --resize <size in MB>`.
5. Launch the VirtualBox application, select `default` VM and click on the “Settings” gear on top.[image: VirtualBox Manager]
6. Click on the “Storage” icon. Remove the default VMDK volume.[image]
7. Add a new IDE controller.[image: IDE controller]
8. Mount the GParted ISO via the “Add CD/DVD Device” option.[image: Add CD/DVD Device]
9. Mount the cloned VDI volume via the “Add CD/DVD Device” option.[image: Mount volume]
10. If you are running Docker on a computer with a solid-state hard drive, please make sure the “Solid-state Drive” option is selected for the cloned VDI volume.[image: Solid-state Drive]
11. Click on the “Start” icon to boot up the Docker virtual machine, which will launch the GParted ISO. Select “GParted Live (Default settings)”.[image: GParted Live (Default settings)]
12. Set the policy for handling keymaps to “Don’t touch keymap”.[image: keymaps]
13. Set language preference to option “33”, which maps to “US English”.[image: US English]
14. Select option “1” to run “Forcevideo” and configure X manually.[image: Forcevideo]
15. Keep the default resolution of “1024×760” by selecting option “2”.[image: 1024×760]
16. Keep the default “vesa” as the VGA card.[image: Leave blank if default is desired]
17. Keep the default colour depth of “24” by selecting option “0”. [image: Colour depth]
18. Once GParted launches, click on the “Resize/Move” icon.[image: GParted]
19. Set the new disk volume size to desired size by dragging the slider. In this example, the maximum size is 127,035MB. Click on the “Resize/Move” button to start the process.[image: Disk volume size]
20. Confirm the resizing operation by clicking on the “Apply” button.[image: Bake it]
21. Power off the machine after the resizing operation finishes.[image: Hard reset, np :)]
22. Remove the GParted ISO.[image: Your almost done]
23. Log into the Docker virtual machine to verify that the volume resizing was successful by starting machine `docker-machine start default`
24. If you experience network issues, restart the docker-machine

Answer (score 15):

You can use Vmware player to resize a vmdk. 
This removes the round trip conversion (noted in other posts) if you want to keep it in vmdk format. Just make sure that when you add the vmdk into vmware, don't click upgrade format when prompted, keep the current one in case VirtualBox doesn't accept it.

Answer (score 11):

For **shrinking** image size I use the following steps:

1. On the client machine `cat /dev/zero > z;sync;sleep 3;sync;rm -f z`
2. Shut down client machine
3. On the host `VBoxManage clonehd "source.vmdk" "cloned.vdi" --format vdi`
4. On the host `VBoxManage modifyhd cloned.vdi --compact`
5. On the host `VBoxManage clonehd "cloned.vdi" "resized.vmdk" --format vmdk`

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12456219/8738113) by Luca the required steps are:

1. Clone the VMDK image to VDI format

   `VBoxManage clonehd "source.vmdk" "cloned.vdi" --format vdi`
2. Resize the VDI image

   `VBoxManage modifyhd "cloned.vdi" --resize 51200`
3. Clone back to VMDK format

   `VBoxManage clonehd "cloned.vdi" "resized.vmdk" --format vmdk`

Step 3 is optional if you can use a VDI image instead.

All these steps can be carried out in the VirtualBox graphical user interface as well, under `File -> Virtual Media Manager`. Select the drive you want to clone, and then choose `Copy`. A dialog opens that allows you to choose the disk format and options. To resize a VDI image, just use the slider in the bottom (click on `Properties` if it's not visible).

Finally, you may need to change the disk size in the guest OS as well:

4. Run the guest OS and resize the disk partition(s). If you are running Linux, you can use `gparted` or `kparted`.

Answer (score 9):

---

**VirtualBox for Windows**

*Resizing your disk file while **preserving** your virtual machine settings!*

---

### Step 1 - Resize the disk file

Start cmd.exe

`cd` to Oracle VM VirtualBox's dir (on 64-bit systems:  `"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\"`)

Run these commands (as above):

```
VBoxManage clonehd "C:\path\to\source.vmdk" "C:\path_to\cloned.vdi" --format vdi
VBoxManage modifyhd "C:\path\to\cloned.vdi" --resize 51200
```

Windows explorer and "copy address as text" via the address bar should help you get the path you need.

On windows system, The VirtaulBox VM directory underneath your user may contain an XML formatted database file of settings you've configured for your VM.  Rename this file, with a `.bak` extension (it has a `.vbox` extension). Rename the original `.vmdk` file with a `.bak` extension as well to avoid another error.  You can now safetly perform the third step without the error message to convert the machine back to `.vmdk` format, or the "duplicate disk" error.

```
VBoxManage clonehd "C:\path_to\cloned.vdi" "C:\path_to\source.vmdk" --format vmdk
```

You will be presented with a **UID token**.  Copy this token by drag-highlighting it from the Windows Command Interpetor window and using the `Ctrl+C` keyboard shortcut.

Open the `.vbox.bak` file in a text editor such as Notepad++.  You'll be presented with an XML-like database file.  Look for these lines:

```
<VirtualBox xmlns="http://www.virtualbox.org/" version="1.16-windows">
  <Machine uuid="{some uid}" name="source disk name" OSType="the_vbox_OS" snapshotFolder="Snapshots" lastStateChange="2043-03-23T00:54:18Z">
    <MediaRegistry>
      <HardDisks>
        <HardDisk uuid="{some uid}" location="C:\path_to\source.vmdk" ...
```

On the line `<HardDisk uuid="{some uid}" location="C:\path_to\source.vmdk" ...`, **delete** the old UID token between the brackets and **paste** the one you copied from the command window.  Make sure that you leave the brackets **in place**!

Save this file, and exit your text editor.  Rename the `.vbox.bak` file to give it back its expected extension of `.vbox`.

---

### Step 2 - Remove the junk

It is now safe to remove the `.bak` files remaining in the directory.  What remains is a resized `.vmdk` with an updated `.vbox` database while with your previously preserved VirtualBox Manager settings.

---

### Step 3 - Resize the disk's partition to fill the free space

You can now start the VirtualBox VM Manager and execute your VM, using the appropriate tools for the operating system to fill the new free space.

For **Windows VMs**, use `diskpart` from the command prompt booted from the Windows Recovery Consule (recovery partition) to `SELECT DISK 1`, `LIST PARTITION` and gather the partition number of your `C:\` drive, then `SELECT PARTITION #`.  You can use the `EXTEND SIZE=mb` to resize the Windows C:\ drive to the appropriate value.  Make sure you leave room for the recovery and boot partitions!  It's safe to subtract 4096 MB from your new virtual disk size to get this value, because of shadow copy and windows recovery files.

For **Linux VMs**, a live `.ISO` of gparted you can boot with the VM's disk file can be found at:  http://gparted.org/  It will get you straight into a graphical user interface-based gparted-gtk, from where you can fill your free space.

For **PPC / Mac VMs**, `Disk Utility` from the Finder will asisst you in filling the free space, but you may want to consider **the gparted Linux option**, as currently the only method of which to boot MacOSX in VirtualBox is hackintosh, and you cannot extend your volume while booted into MacOSX.  You may also want to seek out tweaking the VM's settings temporarily for `gparted`, to get it to boot.  MacOSX partitions are recognized by gparted as `HFS` - "Heaping File System" partitions.

---

### Step 4 - Cat Photos

Because the internet.  ;)  You're finished.  Enjoy your new resized virtual `.vmdk` disk image with VirtualBox for Windows!

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive steps, they were very useful!
Some variations I did: I used disk partition tool to extend my disk volume on my Win10 VM.
Also, there is a missing detailed step, which is to re-add the cloned vmdk disk to the VM configuration. That's it. Cheers!

Comment: The step part to rename the vm config file ".vbox" to ".vbox.bak" **before** cloning is **very important**! if not, the clone action failed

Comment: This is probably the "most complete" answer if you're getting errors from your failed VBoxManage commands.  In my case, even when I renamed the config file to "*.vbox.bak" somehow VBox still retained state (via registry?).  So I had to just use additional VBoxManage commands.  For instance, to view virtual disks:  `vboxmanage list hdds`.  To remove unwanted ones:  `vboxmanage closemedium disk <filename.vmdk>`.  View the SATA port#,device# :  `vboxmanage showvminfo <vmName>`.  To DETACH disk:  `vboxmanage storageattach <vmName> --storagectl SATA --port <p#> --device <d#> --medium none`

Answer (score 7):

Here's a way to resize your VirtualBox disk, regardless of whether it is a fixed format or dynamic format disk. Specifically, it prevents the error you had when you disk is fixed-format.

---

> ⚠️ Backup the virtual disk. You never know what might go wrong.

On your host:

1. Open a terminal window.

   > On Windows: Open the command prompt `cmd`.
2. Go to the directory with the virtual disk you want to resize. For example:

   ```sh
   cd "My VMs"
   ```
3. Create a new VirtualBox disk with your desired filename, size (in megabytes) and format (either `Standard` (dynamic) or `Fixed`). For example, to create a 50 GB fixed-format disk called `MyNewDisk.vdi`:

   ```sh
   VBoxManage createmedium --filename "MyNewDisk.vdi" --size 50000 --variant Fixed
   ```

   > If `VBoxManage` is not recognized as a command, specify the full path to it. It can be found in the VirtualBox installation directory. On Windows the above command would become:
   >
   > ```sh
   > "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" createmedium
   >     --filename "MyNewDisk.vdi" --size 50000 --variant Fixed
   > ```
4. Copy the original disk to the new disk.

   ```sh
   VBoxManage clonemedium "MyOriginalDisk.vdi" "MyNewDisk.vdi" --existing
   ```
5. The resize is done! You can check the properties of the new disk if you want:

   ```sh
   VBoxManage showmediuminfo "MyNewDisk.vdi"
   ```
6. Change the virtual machine to use the new disk instead.

Next, on your guest OS you need to resize the partitions to use the newly available space.

Answer (score 3):

I've got here because I needed to resize a disk for my Docker (CoreOS) development environment.

CoreOS docs says there's no need to resize the OS partition - that's bogus. After you resize the virtual disk you should follow these instructions and resize the OS partition via GParted:

https://docs.docker.com/articles/b2d_volume_resize/

Answer (score 3):

A quick and simple option:

1. Turn off machine
2. Create new virtual box disk with desired size
3. Move content from old disk to inside new disk:

   ```
   vboxmanage clonehd "source-disk.vmdk" "new-disk.vmdk" --existing
   ```
4. Turn on machine
5. You may have to resize partition in OS to fill the rest of the disk

---

**Warning**

If new disk is shorter than source, you will **loss the data** located from the new disk size position on the source disk.

You may prevent this deallocating delta space, where delta = size(source-disk) - size(new-disk), at the end of source disk inside OS before step 1.

Answer (score 1):

Use these simple steps to resize the vmdk.

1. Click the `File -> Virtual Media Player`

[image]

2. Select vdi file and click `properties`

[image]

Here you can increase or decrease the vdi size.