# resize .vdi in Oracle VirtualBOx not working in Windows 7

Tags: windows, virtual-machine

I tried to resize my .vmdk as reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659005/how-to-resize-a-virtualbox-vmdk-file/11659046#11659046).
I had some trible but I managed to clone my firsd disk.
Now I try to resize my new disk but I get again the following error:

```
VBoxManage.exe: error: Resize hard disk operation for this format is not implemented yet!
```

I have no idea how to fix this. Any suggestion?

**Update**

I colend my .vmdh hdd into a new .vi hdd.
I tried then to increase the size using

```
modifyhd NAME.vdi --resize 256000
```

Immidiatelly I got a completed work, no errors. I restart my windows session. But the size of the new .vdi is still the same. Any suggestion how to fix this?

**Update 2**

Ok now I used GParted iso to resize my partition as explained [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/124622/how-to-enlarge-a-virtual-machines-disk-in-virtualbox-or-vmware/).
In fact when I hopen the Virtual Machine I see tha the size is 250 G

[image]

So I started to install heavy things on my Linux account, but now Linux tells me that I have no space anymore, even though the used space is around 39 G.
Where is my mistake?

Comment: It doesn't even look like this is an error. What format is it? What kind of appliance?

Comment: I am using Windows 7, Virtual Box  4.3.18 and after cloning my disk is in *.vdi format

Comment: Can you post the exact command you are issuing to resize please?

Comment: VBoxManage modifyhd "Path\to my\hdd.vdi" --resize 256000

Comment: Are you sure the virtual disk is set to dynamically-resize? Also [this](http://superuser.com/questions/716649/how-to-change-fixed-size-vdi-with-modifyhd-command-in-windows) seems to have a lot of info on your issue.

Comment: Ok, great! this is really good! I checekd wioth `showhdinfo` and basically the `Format Version: dynamic default` and what I do not really understand is that `Capacity: 256000 MBytes` but `Size on disk: 38999 MBytes`.Any idea?

Comment: I would assume that means that the size on your PC of the image is 38Gb but it has the capacity to hold 250Gb. Since it is dynamically expandable it will expand up to that limit.