# Lubuntu. /bin/sh: 2: xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc: not found

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, compiler-errors, esp8266, xtensa

I'm am a very beginner at this area and I have a problem compiling an example from [ESP8266_NONOS_SDK-master](https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_NONOS_SDK).
I've been following steps described in **ESP8266 SDK Getting Started Guide** form the [documentation](https://espressif.com/en/support/download/documents?keys=&field_type_tid%5B%5D=14).
That means that I downloaded virtual box esp8266 image (ESP8266_lubuntu_20141021.ova) where all tools as I understood must be set up.
But while compiling the example I am getting:

```
/bin/sh: 2: xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc: not found
```

error.

`echo $PATH` returns: `/opt/xtensa-lx106-elf/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/us‌​r/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbi‌​n:/bin:/usr/games:/u‌​sr/local/games:/snap‌​/bin`

and `xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc -v` returns `Configured with ...gcc version 4.8.2 (crosstool-NG 1.20.0)`

The compilation happens under **esp8266/Share** folder.

Can someone tell me what am I missing and how to get SDK to 'see' xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc?

Lubuntu directory tree image:
[image]

Comment: @mpromonet  echo $PATH returns:
`/opt/xtensa-lx106-elf/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`
so it's already there. also `xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc -v` returns `Configured with ...gcc version 4.8.2 (crosstool-NG 1.20.0) `

Comment: it could be nice to add this information to your post, otherwise it seems the PATH have not be set.

Comment: @mpromonet Done. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Xtensa crosstool-NG was missing. To install it used [this](https://github.com/esp8266/esp8266-wiki/wiki/Toolchain#install-the-xtensa-crosstool-ng-as-local-user) method. (Do not forget to `chown $username /opt/espressif/` in order to avoid   'Permission denied' error while compilation.
 Also to upgrade OS (if this is chosen) and build crosstool-NG in /opt/espressif, [enlarge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12456219/1990161) VM disc size, as it might run out of free space.)