# Citrix XenCenter, adding more space to a linux server, but space is unusable

Tags: linux, citrix, ext2

I wish it was as easy as
[VirtualBox: extend partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141045/virtualbox-extend-partition)
But its not.

You see in Citrix Xen center Instead of adding a virtual harddisk I just shut the server off and made its vhd* bigger, and that results in more space on a partition I cant seem to use.

*fdisk -l* gives this.

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvda1   *           1          43      340992   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/xvda2              43        5222    41598977    5  Extended
/dev/xvda5              43        1137     8787968   83  Linux
/dev/xvda6            1137        1502     2928640   83  Linux
/dev/xvda7            1502        1625      989184   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/xvda8            1625        1674      389120   83  Linux
/dev/xvda9            1674        5222    28499968   83  Linux
```

xvda2 is the culprit, see how big it is. I want to mount this somewhere to have space for backups.
I have tried *mkfs, fdisk /dev/xvda2* and it seems that this partition is just wrong.

```
 fdisk /dev/xvda2

 Unable to read /dev/xvda2
```

I have tried mkfs *defaults to ext2 of fstype*

```
mkfs /dev/xvda2 41598900
mke2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
mkfs.ext2: Filesystem larger than apparent device size.
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
Warning: could not erase sector 2: Attempt to write block from filesystem resulted in short write
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
2599968 inodes, 10399725 blocks
519986 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=4294967296
318 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8176 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,
        4096000, 7962624

mkfs.ext2: Invalid argument while zeroing block 10399696 at end of filesystem
Writing inode tables:   0/318
Could not write 5 blocks in inode table starting at 1027: Invalid argument
```

I can't mount it.

```
mount -t ext2 /dev/xvda2 /mnt/extra/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvda2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

I have googled and googled and googled, but I haven't come up with something that works in this case being that I added to the vhd from citrix xen center.

Answer (score 0):

/dev/xvda2 is an extended partition. It's like a container for logical partitions. That means there's extra space, probably at the end of /dev/xvda.

Comment: @AustinAdams You'll have to use `fdisk` to create another partition at the end of the disk.

Comment: @AustinAdams Correction: you could resize the partitions, and I think you'd have to expand /dev/xvda2 and then one of the logical partitions within it, like /dev/xvda9.

Comment: but doing an fdisk on /dev/xvda/ and the n and then l says no free sectors available